# MYSQL Calculate total minutes from timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to sum total minutes from timestamps.

my data is like

```
2017-03-11 14:27:06
2017-03-11 14:27:12
2017-03-11 14:27:16
2017-03-11 14:27:20
2017-03-11 14:27:24
2017-03-11 14:27:28
2017-03-11 14:27:32
2017-03-11 14:27:36
2017-03-11 14:27:42
2017-03-11 14:27:50
2017-03-11 14:27:54
2017-03-11 14:28:02
2017-03-11 14:28:11
```

And I want to sum total minutes from this data. what should I do for this ?

Comment: Please elaborate on what results you want.

Comment: What should the total minutes be? Is it the number of minutes between the earliest and latest date/times? Are these start/stop pairs of values (given the odd number of entries, unlikely)?

Answer (score 2):

I speculate that you want the amount of time spanned by the data.  If so, a simple way is to use `to_seconds()` and convert back to minutes:

```
select (to_seconds(max(col)) - to_seconds(min(col))) / 60 as minutes
from t;
```

Or, if you want an integer:

```
select timestampdiff(day, min(col), max(col))
from t;
```

Comment: Actually I want to calculate sum seconds in the row not the range

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate sum of all minutes of each row from a table you can use following query and you can achieve this by MINUTE() function of mysql , it will extract minutes from a timestamp column

```
select sum(min) from (select minute(timestamp_column_of_table) as min from table_name) as temp_table;
```